# WebDriverIO: Return Visible Elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, ecmascript-6, webdriver-io

I'm working on a test suite with WebDriverIO in which the site being tested has several duplicate elements, but they selectively appear by user interaction...

For instance, there could be five buttons that open five tooltips -- but each tooltip is a copy of the others (same class names, data properties, all that fun stuff).

Is there a way for me to capture/return *just* the visible tooltips?

I can capture true/false by using...

```
let visElements = browser.isVisible('div.tooltip');
```

(which returns an array like `[false, true, false, false, false]`)
Is there a way to return the truthful element for additional testing?

**Update:**

My not so elegant solution, so far...

```
let visElements = browser.elements('div.tooltip');
let visBool     = browser.isVisible('div.tooltip');
let index       = (visBool === true)? 0 : visBool.indexOf(true);
let element     = visElements.value[index];
```

... this really only works because the code I'm working with should only show one tooltip at a time.  Any other scenario it can easily go bollocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the newish `find` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) available on arrays to search through that array for the one visible element:

```
let tooltips = browser.elements('div.tooltip');

let visibleTooltip = tooltips.find(tt => tt.isVisible())

// can do any element function on it like getText
visibleTooltip.getText()
```

If you want to get all the visible tooltips, you can [use `filter` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
let tooltips = browser.elements('div.tooltip');

let visibleTooltips = tooltips.filter(tt => tt.isVisible())

// can do any element function on it like getText
let ttText = visibleTooltips.map(tt => tt.getText())
```